# Using jagged with multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

New member here.  There are a lot of posts about arrays, but I haven't seen this so I'm wondering if this is possible.

I have a gameboard that is 11 x 10. I have an array to lay out the squares.  The top row is a[0][0] - a[0][10] and the bottom row is a[9][0] - a[9][10] and the inbetween is as you would expect.

Think of the board as a checker board. A piece moves to a square and is placed in the array at that particular spot.  The twist is that you can have a stack of pieces on one square.  That's where the jagged array comes in, because the number of pieces in the stacks can vary.

My question is, can I nest a jagged array in the multidemensional array at each point on the board?

The only other way I can think to do it would be to have 110 jagged arrays, one at each location without the multidimensional array at all.  Would that be the way to do it?

I know I have a lot to learn about arrays, so if someone could just point me in the direction of what I should be looking up it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure - the syntax would be `a[][][]`.  It's a jagged array of jagged arrays of arrays.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I had a jagged array in the bottom corner it would be a[9][0][0], a[9][0][1], a[9][0][2] etc as it moved up the array?

Comment: Why are you using a jagged array instead of a multi-dimensional array?  The whole point of a jagged array is that it can be jagged.  Your game board obviously has the same number of columns in each row and that is exactly how a multi-dimensional array works.

Comment: You are correct about the gameboard, but the multi-dimensional array will not handle the pieces that stack in the same square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of pieces in a stack can vary, it seems to me what you really want is a two-dimensional array representing the game board, which contains instances of the stacks. These can some custom data type, or you could just use `List<T>` (e.g. `List<Piece>` where `Piece` is your game piece type).

For example:

```
List<Piece>[,] board = new List<Piece>[11,10];

for (int row = 0; row < 11; row++)
    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
        board[row, column] = new List<Piece>();
```

By using `List<T>` here, then your board starts with an empty list in each place, and you can add or remove pieces simply by adding or removing them from the list.

If "stacks" are in fact a discrete gameplay unit themselves, then it might make more sense to represent those as a custom type. And in that case (depending on how gameplay works) you might in fact reassign stacks in each board array element. I don't know…there's not really enough information in your question to go that deeply into implementation specifics.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Good point you make with the discrete gameplay unit. When your piece moves on top of the stack, you will have the choice to move off onto another square or to move the stack as one unit. Using a list never crossed my mind.  I can't say for sure this would be the best choice, but your answer was perfect as far as giving me a foothold.  Now I can dig in and start to put it together.  Time will tell whether it works, but I wasn't expecting a solution as much as I was a direction.  Thanks.